# Finding and extracting the substring from a damaged text

Tags: python

It is easy to find a substring in a string, like the following:

```
substring: "060MHXEA"
string: "DVM MINI(RD040/050/060MHXGA, RD040/050/060MHXEA)"
```

But if the string is destroyed, like the following;

```
string: DV@@ M MIN@@ I ( R@@ D@@ 0@@ 40 / 0@@ 50 / 06@@ 0@@ M@@ H@@ X@@ GA , R@@ D@@ 0@@ 40 / 0@@ 50 / 06@@ 0@@ M@@ H@@ X@@ EA )
```

How can I find and extract `"06@@ 0@@ M@@ H@@ X@@ EA"` from the string, since it is the destroyed form of `060MHXEA`?

Note: Destruction is done by splitting chars with `"@@ "` in my case.

Comment: You need to extract and __destructed__ string or the normalized one? And also I should as about one thing - are destruction chars always same or you need to find them in code?

Comment: I need to extract the destructed form of the substring from the destructed string.

Comment: are destructions known for you? Or you should find them?

Comment: I have the destructed text. But I don't know how it is destructed. The only thing I know is the destruction is done by "@@ ". But I don't know exactly at which part of text it is being done.

Comment: if the destructions always done with "@@ ", then wait for solution. I'll post an answer soon

Comment: have you try to just remove "@" , `string = string.replace("@", "")` ? and then find your `substring`... ?

Comment: I can find the substring, but I need to know the original destructed form of that substring.

Comment: why can’t you just remove the destructors?

Comment: I need the destructed text, taylor.

Comment: @yusuf I almost did it, but only stuck on list with normalized text and positions of chars in destructed text. I can share my work with you now, but it's incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING!** That solution may be irrational, feel free to improve algorithm in your answers.

Full code is here: https://repl.it/Gn3N

Generate our first list with format `[[character, 0]]` (where `character` - chars from initial string `a`), then replace all zeros with indexes (via `range()`, it's important):

```
a = 'DV@@ M MIN@@ I ( R@@ D@@ 0@@ 40 / 0@@ 50 / 06@@ 0@@ M@@ H@@ X@@ GA , R@@ D@@ 0@@ 40 / 0@@ 50 / 06@@ 0@@ M@@ H@@ X@@ EA )'

positions = [[x, 0] for x in a]

for x in range(len(positions)):
    positions[x][1] = x
```

Then, we are going to define function-clearer, which replace our substring-damager in `positions`, while keeping it's initial indexes:

```
def clearer(lst):
     trig = []
     for x in lst:
         if x[0] is '@':
             trig.append(x)
         elif x[0] is ' ' and x[1] == trig[-1][1]+1:
             trig.append(x)
     for x in trig:
         lst.remove(x)
     return lst

clr = clearer(positions)
```

Now, we should look for index of first occurrence of substring in cleared text, generate range with **initial** indexes and iterate over initial text with it:

```
substr = '060MHXEA'

indexes = range(clr[''.join([x[0] for x in clr]).find(substr)][1], clr[''.join([x[0] for x in clr]).find(substr)+len(substr)][1])

result = ''

for x in indexes:
     result += a[x]
print(result) #06@@ 0@@ M@@ H@@ X@@ EA
```

Comment: @yusuf what's wrong? It works even with another substrings

Comment: @yusuf what's the error? Post full text. Are you sure you using Python 3? It works in sandbox https://repl.it/Gn3N